# setState and avoid mutating existing properties

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, lodash

I do

```
const user = this.state.user;
this.setState({
  user: {
   id
  }
});
```

but my other properties is gone. It used to have

`user.name, user.gender` etc. How can I keep a copy of existing object and update the state? use lodash's clone method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you don't need lodash to do it. try

```
let updatedUser = Object.assign({}, this.state.user, {
  id
})

this.setState({
  user: updatedUser
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at [Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) for solving this problem.

But, I would recommend you to use [immutability-helper](https://github.com/kolodny/immutability-helper):

```
import update from 'immutability-helper';

const user = this.state.user;
const updatedUser = update(user, {
  id: {$set: 7}
});

this.setState({user: updatedUser});
```

Here, `$set` is a command for the `update` function to set a new value for `user.id`. Rest of the properties in your user object will remain unchanged.

While the syntax takes a little getting used to, it's much easier once you understand it. For simple state objects, Object.assign is fine.

However, if your state object is very complex and deep, cloning the entire state might impact performance. This is where immutability-helper helps.